# Como puedo saber el valor de un checkBox marcado con vueJS

Tags: php, javascript, laravel, vue.js

Me encuentro terminando un proyecto con Laravel y vueJS, pero tengo un problema. En un modal, selecciono un checkbox (puede haber varios o no) y ese valor del checkbox marcado, necesito mantenerlo para cuando pulse un botón de otro modal, el valor del checkbox se mande al controlado para hacer una actualización. Me lo hace bien con el primer check, pero si selecciono otro me coge siempre el primero. Estoy intentando capturarlo por clase, pero nada, siempre coge el primero.

Adjunto mi código actual:

```
<div class="modal-body">
                    <div v-if="bonosUsuarioSolicitante.length == 0">No hay bonos disponibles</div>
                    <div v-for="data in bonosUsuarioSolicitante" class="ml-5">

                        <label class="form-check-label">Tiempo Restante</label>
                        <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input ml-3 codContrato" :value="data.codContrato" @click="iniciarActuacion">
                        <label class="form-check-label ml-5">{{data["tiempoRestanteBono"]}} Min</label>

                    </div>
                </div>
```

Ahí pongo los valores de los checkbox dentro del modal eso llama a la función "iniciarActuación" hasta ahí bien. Si todo va bien, este modal se cierra.

En otro modal, tengo esto:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" @click="detenerActuacion">Detener Actuacion</button>
```

y esta función, es la que ya actualizaría

```
detenerActuacion: function(){
            clearInterval(cronometro);

            let minutosContratados = $("#tiempoContratado").val();

            // Mínimo se va a restar 5 minutos a la actuación una vez iniciada.
            let minutosActuacion = 5

            let minutosEmpleados = document.getElementById("minutos").innerText;

            if(minutosEmpleados < minutosActuacion){
                minutosEmpleados = minutosActuacion;
            }


            // variables que van al controlador
            let tiempoEmpleadoCalculado = minutosContratados - minutosEmpleados;


            let mensaje = $("#mensajeActuacion").val();
            let codV3 = $("#codV3").val();
            let codContrato = $(".codContrato").val();
           
            let url = "/actualizarTiempo";
            axios
                .post(url, {
                            tiempoEmpleado: minutosEmpleados,
                            tiempoRestante: tiempoEmpleadoCalculado,
                            mensajeActuacion: mensaje,
                            codContrato: codContrato,
                            codV3: codV3,
                           }
                      )
                .then((response) => {
                    $("#actuacionCorrecta").text("Actuación guardada con exito y tiempo del bono actualizado")
                })
                .catch(
                    (error) => $("#actuacionError").append(error)

                );
        },
```

Se que tengo mezclado jquery y que no se debería de hacer usando vueJS, pero no se hacerlo de otra manera. En el primer modal es donde podría obtener el codContrato que es lo que necesito para actualizar. De ahí que lo intente capturar con clase. Como digo, el primero va bien... Pero ya está.

PD: se que jquery no es lo más correcto, lo digo otra vez, quiero que sea lo más correcto posible

Un saludo y gracias de antemano.

Comment: Tienes que ocuár un v-model y un on change obtienes el valor de ese

Comment: @FernandoTorres gracias por tu respuesta, ya lo he solucionado. Si era usando v-model.